# Using Python to find a know difference

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I have an excel extract of my vat account and I am familiar with some python coding, still starting out. I have a particular value of "Z". But I am unsure what values made this value "Z". So for instance I am unsure what (X + Y = Z) values X and Y are but I know the value of Z. Z could be X and Y added together, or multiplied or even a percentage of. It is more likely a percentage as I am working with a tax account.

Am I able to get a python code that will run through all the values I have in my tax account and do all of the below:
add
subtract
multiply
percentage of
Until it finds which values make up my value of Z?

Example of Spreadsheet:
Column A
50000,
25000,
681,
9999,
48569,

I am looking for a value of 31004 for example. This value could come from value 3 being subtracted from value 1. Or it could be a percentage(15%) of both value 4 and 5 added together. I am trying to determine which values have made up my value and if it was a percentage of or just a standard add or subtract.

I hope this question was clear.

I have not tried anything yet as I am not that familiar with python. I have started out practicing data frames.

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you share a minimal reproducible example of your spreadsheet/dataframe (`print(df.sample(5).to_dict("list"))`) -- _assuming df is your dataframe_ -- and the matching expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have made an edit to my question which includes an example of the spreadsheet.

Comment: I understand that you want to evalulate all the _possible calculations_ that lead to your input number from the list of numbers in the `Column A`. I think you can make this up by implementing a __Reverse Polish Notation__. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: Everything I see about reverse polish notation is that I would need to know the expression. In my case I only know one value that I am trying to work out but I am unsure what variation of all my numbers will make up that value.